# httpdispatcher returning no or blank response

Tags: node.js

I have the following simple code for a nodejs server....

```
var http = require('http');
var port = 1337;
var dispatcher = require('httpdispatcher');

dispatcher.setStaticDirname(__dirname);
dispatcher.setStatic('');

dispatcher.onGet("/page1", function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('Page One');
});

var server = http.createServer().listen(port);


server.on('request', function (req, res) {
    console.log('GOT');
    dispatcher.dispatch(req, res);  
});
console.log('Listening on port %s', port);
```

when I goto http://localhost:1337/index.html it is showing up correctly but when I do http://localhost:1337/page1 nothing happens...how can I get it to function properly...

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your custom dispatcher events, in this case "/page1", before setting the static dispatcher. Otherwise static hogs every possible path remaining to check against the file system.

```
dispatcher.onGet("/page1", function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('Page One');
});

dispatcher.setStaticDirname(__dirname);
dispatcher.setStatic('');
```

Your revised code will look like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var port = 1337;
var dispatcher = require('httpdispatcher');


dispatcher.onGet("/page1", function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('Page One');
});

dispatcher.setStaticDirname(__dirname);
dispatcher.setStatic('');

var server = http.createServer().listen(port);

server.on('request', function (req, res) {
    console.log('GOT');
    dispatcher.dispatch(req, res);  
});
console.log('Listening on port %s', port);
```

Tested and works